# Issue importing pandas library 'module' object has no attribute 'python_version'

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

My anaconda-based pandas install was working fine and then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/xx/xx/test.py", line 3, in <module>
import pandas
File "/home/sc9/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
File "tslib.pyx", line 39, in init pandas.tslib (pandas/tslib.c:63127)
File "/home/sc9/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
from pkg_resources import resource_stream
File "/home/sc9/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1366, in <module>

File "/home/sc9/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-12.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1370, in MarkerEvaluation

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_version'
```

running `python` `test.py` on this simple file is enough to reproduce:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas
```

I think this line (1370) `'python_full_version':` `platform.python_version` might be the problem as `platform.py` does not have a `python_version` attribute only the `python_version()` function. However I have never changed this and I don't see why it has stopped working when all was fine.

This error has also followed me from one ubuntu machine to another so I guess it must be something I'm doing in code rather than a corrupted library.

Strangely an IPython (2.2.0) console can run `import pandas` `as` `pd` fine but a regular python console will fail with the same error as above. I can debug my code from Pycharm but can't run, which is bemusing to me.

Any help appreciated.

I am developing principally in Pycharm using using python 2.7.9 (Anaconda 2.1.0), Pandas 0.14.1 on Ubuntu 14.0.4

Update: I tried running the simple import from a different directory using a regular python console and it worked. I found an import statement which looks like it might be causing the problem with the project I was working on: `from twisted.python.runtime import platform` this is used to do a platform check. I thought removing this would fix the problem but it seems to be persisting somewhere because it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=761980

Comment: Thanks for that @unutbu. It has helped me narrow the problem down. I have a subdirectory in my project that I was running code from from there I open a python console and run `import pkg_resources` and get the attribute error. I then `cd ../` to a higher level directory within my project tree and do the same thing with no error. There is nothing wrong with pkg_resources or pandas but something in that directory is messing things up. I suspect it was that import of platform but that is gone now so although I know the troublesome directory I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I moved the all of the files in that directory into a different directory and ran them and they worked. There was no hidden files or `.pyc` files so I don't know what was corrupting these files when sitting in that directory. Leaving open as I'd still like to put those files back into that directory if anyone knows what might be causing this.